# How to print json property name on nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a json in the following format:

```
{
 "nm_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Nome do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "ds_questionario":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Descri&ccedil;&atilde;o do Question&aacute;rio"},
 "dt_inicio_vigencia":{"isEmpty":"MSGE1 - Data de Vig&ecirc;ncia"}
}
```

How can I print the names of the properties using nifi? I want to retrieve the names `nm_questionario`, `dt_inicio_vigencia` and `ds_questionario`. Tried many things already but to no avail.

Comment: Where do you want them to print?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `LogAttribute` processor with *Log payload* set to `true` to print the full contents in your `$NIFI_HOME/logs/nifi-app.log` file. You can also use a `PutFile` processor to write the contents to a flat file on disk. If you need to do something programmatic with those values, you can use the `EvaluateJSONPath` processor to extract various pieces of content into named attributes, which you can manage using `UpdateAttribute` or `LogAttribute` again.

Comment: Thanks so much @Andy! Worked perfectly.